# one variable changes dynamically depending on previous variable

Tags: php, variables, loops, while-loop

i have this div inside loop

what i want to do is

if the **first `<div>`** take **`$a` variable** the **second `<div>`** want it to take **`$b` variable**  and so on

so basically the structure will be

```
<?php
    $a = '1';
    $b = '2';

    while(...){

        //// if this div take $a variable 
       //// the next div will take $b variable 
      //// and the 3rd div take $a variable and so on

        echo "<div id='$a OR $b'>This is a Div</div>";

    }
?>
```

Comment: please post VALID code.

Comment: also, `id`s should be unique, so the whole task doesn't make sense.

Comment: You state you want to `enter a number randomly`, but from your code it seems like you want to just use whichever value wasn't used last? Which isn't random...it's just alternating the values...which is it that you're after?

Comment: just edited the question to be more understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

you need only one variable that changes dynamically.

```
<?php
    $a = '1';
    while(...)
    {
        echo "<div id='$a'>This is a Div</div>";
        if($a=='1') $a='2';
        else $a='1'
    }

?>
```

Comment: oh, it made by mistake, i just corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$a = '1';
$b = '2';

while(...){

//// if this div take $a variable so the next div will take $b variable and the 3rd div take $a variable and so on

echo "<div id='".rand(1, 2)."'>This is a Div</div>";

}

?>
```

Comment: sometimes it show 1 in first and 1 in second

Comment: Yes, this is random show :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $a = '1';
    $b = '2';

    while(...){
        if($c == $a) $c = $b;
        else $c = $a;
        echo "<div id='".$c."'>This is a Div</div>";

    }
?>
```